# Python KeyError | API Response

Tags: python, json, api, response, keyerror

I created a wrapper for an API I am using. The full wrapper is here: https://pastebin.com/nL089zwF

I am running a call using the following code:

```
balanceBTC = api.GetBalance('BTC')
for i in balanceBTC['data']:
    if i['symbol'] == 'btc':
        print i['available']
```

The response is the following:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'respond'
```

Trace identifies line 50 of the code as the issue:

```
return response.respond["false","False"].respond["true","True"].respond['":null','":None' ]
```

So I removed .respond and was left with a new error:

```
return response["false","False"], ["true","True"], ['":null','":None' ]
KeyError: ('false', 'False')
```

I know the response is a dict and it doesn't have a key and that's what's causing the error (i think?) but I am a beginner learning as I go and I do not know what to change/add/delete on the code itself.

I'd appreciate guidance on what to do! Thank you.

Below is the full section of the API wrapper responsible for getting the response:

```
def api_query(self, method, values, req = None ):
            if not req:
                req = {}
            #print "def api_query( method = " + method + ", req = " + str( req ) + " ):"
            time.sleep(1)
            if method in self.public:
                url = 'https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/'
            elif method in self.private:
                url = 'https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/'
            else:
                return 'Call Not Identified - Something Went Wrong.'

            url += method + '?' + urllib.urlencode(values)

            if method not in self.public:
                url = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Api/" + method
                nonce = str( int( time.time() ) )
                post_data = json.dumps( req );
                m = hashlib.md5()
                m.update(post_data)
                requestContentBase64String = base64.b64encode(m.digest())
                signature = self.key + "POST" + urllib.quote_plus( url ).lower() + nonce + requestContentBase64String
                hmacsignature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode( self.secret ), signature, hashlib.sha256).digest())
                header_value = "amx " + self.key + ":" + hmacsignature + ":" + nonce
                headers = { 'Authorization': header_value, 'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
                r = requests.post( url, data = post_data, headers = headers )
            response = json.loads(r.text)

            return response.respond["false","False"].respond["true","True"].respond['":null','":None' ]
```

Comment: seems the api requires key and secret, so we probably can't reproduce the error. But you can confirm what type response is - what does `print type(response)` show? Depends on which definition of response you use. `response = r.text` should show `<type 'str'>`, whereas `response = json.loads(r.text)`, then `type(response)` should show `<type 'dict'>`

Comment: It does require them, I have them inputted in a file called secrets.json. it pulls the key and secret from that file. I used response = r.text before and it gives me the error TypeError: string indices must be integers so I switched it to response = json.loads(r.text) and get the KeyError... Sorry if this isn't clear. Any idea? @downshift

Comment: `json.loads(r)` will only work if `r` is a dictionary, `<type 'dict'>`, and `r.text` should be `type(r.text)` -> 
`<type 'unicode'>`. What content or `type` of content do you want the method to return? The text of the response? A boolean value, like `True`/`False`?

Comment: Text response, it's a number with up to 8 decimal places i.e. 1.12345678

Comment: `response.text` contains a number? It may be a number represented as a `'unicode'` string - what does `type(r.text)` output? This number is what you want to return in the function call?

Comment: In this case, yes. I want the number to return. GetBalance gets the amount of a specified cryptocurrency. So balanceBTC = api.GetBalance('BTC') ... should return the amount of BTC i.e. 1.12345678.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Then can you use `return r.text`?

Comment: Just tried replacing response = r.text with return r.text and it now gives a new error..

 `File "C:\Users\Userl\Documents\Crypto Scripts\Cryptopia\test3.py", line 38, in <module>
    for i in balanceBTC['data']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Right, that's because `balanceBTC` contains the number, i.e. 1.12345678 (that you get back from `api.GetBalance('BTC')`), which cannot be indexed by strings like `'data'`.

Comment: What do you want the first block of code to do? The function call will return the number, but then you iterate over the number like it is a dictionary checking for `if i['symbol'] == 'btc':` to get a `boolean`. I think that's what's causing confusion.

Comment: Thanks figured it out! Problem was it was 'Data' rather than 'data'

Comment: Oh wow I would have never figured that out, lol, good job 

Answer (score 0):

late edit : 
Error solved, it was getting the wrong key ('data', instead of 'Data')

Correct version is here anyway (the one used).

```
def api_query(self, method, values, req = None ):
if not req:
    req = {}
time.sleep(1)
if method in self.public:
    url = 'https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/'
elif method in self.private:
     url = 'https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/'
else:
    return 'Call Not Identified - Something Went Wrong.'
url += method + '?' + urllib.urlencode(values)
if method not in self.public:
    url = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/Api/" + method
    nonce = str( int( time.time() ) )
    post_data = json.dumps( req );
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(post_data)
    requestContentBase64String = base64.b64encode(m.digest())
    signature = self.key + "POST" + urllib.quote_plus( url ).lower() + nonce + requestContentBase64String
    hmacsignature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode( self.secret ), signature, hashlib.sha256).digest())
    header_value = "amx " + self.key + ":" + hmacsignature + ":" + nonce
   headers = { 'Authorization': header_value, 'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
    r = requests.post( url, data = post_data, headers = headers )
return r.json() #changed here
```